# java, for loop help for very basic ASCII console output

Tags: java, for-loop, ascii

writing some simple `ASCII` thing which basically for now is just printing out a char for each pixel with a defined width and height.

i have a for loop that adds the chars to a string and adds "\n" when width is reached so that width and height are correct.

however its currently printing one too many on first line and one too few on the last any ideas??

passing this to the `method ('.', 7,5)`

```
private String format(char character, int width, int height)
{
    char[] picture = new char[width * height];
    String pic = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
    {
        picture[i] = character;
        pic += picture[i];

        if(i == width || i > width  && i % width == 0)
        {
            pic += "\n";

        }
    }
    return pic;
}
```

and this is my output

........
.......
.......
.......
......

ok well each block of those dots are meant to be on different lines but for some reason its putting them in a row, anyway you can still see that first row has 8 and last row has 6?

Comment: I don't understand why are you building both string and a character array? And you are not using the character array at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your new-line appending up in the loop:

```
if(i > 0 && (i % width) == 0)
{
    pic += "\n";
}
picture[i] = character;
pic += picture[i];
```

and you should definitely use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for building strings.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked, and was soo simple dont know why i didnt think of that knew it would be something easy but after you look at something so long u cant see the obvious.

Comment: and i havent encountered string builder but ill take a look cheers for the advice